# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object with a tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a basic tkinter program that generates a GUI, my goal is that when you press the "Encrypt button"

```py
Encrypt_btn = Button(text="Encrypt", command= lambda: Encrypt(Encrypt_box.get(1.0, END)))
```

it calls the encrypt function:

```py
def Encrypt(string):
    answer = Encrypter_part.encrypter(string)
    Encrypt_output_box.insert(INSERT, answer)
```

which calls a different file:

```
def encrypter(message_copy):
    global alphabet
    global password_chars
    dd = []
    official_message = []
    encryption_key = 0
    encryption_key = random.randint(1, 999999999)
    ff = []
    keep_first_num = 0
    for i in range(len(message_copy)):
        password_chars.append(message_copy[i])
    encrypter(message_copy)
    for i in message_copy:
        dd.append(round(alphabet.index(i) * (encryption_key * 37876/42.71)))
    dd = dd[::-1]
    dd.append(encryption_key)
    for num in dd:
        ff.append(num)
        ff.append(random.randint(1, 999999999999999999))
    keep_first_num = ff[0:len(ff)-1]
    return keep_first_num
```

But I get this error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\PycharmProjects\encrypter_gui\main.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    Encrypt_btn = Button(text="Encrypt", command= lambda: Encrypt(Encrypt_box.get(1.0, END)))
  File "C:\Users\mathi\PycharmProjects\encrypter_gui\main.py", line 20, in Encrypt
    answer = Encrypter_part.encrypter(string)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\PycharmProjects\encrypter_gui\Encrypter_part.py", line 23, in encrypter
    encrypter(message_copy)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\PycharmProjects\encrypter_gui\Encrypter_part.py", line 23, in encrypter
    encrypter(message_copy)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\PycharmProjects\encrypter_gui\Encrypter_part.py", line 23, in encrypter
    encrypter(message_copy)
  [Previous line repeated 987 more times]
  File "C:\Users\mathi\PycharmProjects\encrypter_gui\Encrypter_part.py", line 18, in encrypter
    encryption_key = random.randint(1, 999999999)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 338, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 314, in randrange
    return istart + self._randbelow(width)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 243, in _randbelow_with_getrandbits
    k = n.bit_length()  # don't use (n-1) here because n can be 1
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`
```

I'm pretty new to this so if you guys could help me with this I would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from your code:

```py
def encrypter(message_copy):
    ...
    encrypter(message_copy)
```

That is an endless loop. I have no idea what you are trying to do with that function but you will always get a `RecursionError` if you call the same function over and over again without changing arguments (in this case `message_copy`) each time you call it.